# How to make Abe query MySQL instead of reading from the bitcoin block.dat for each request?

Tags: transactions, blockchain, bitcoind, abe

After getting abe set up and running, I tried querying it, eg: `...:2750/chain/Bitcoin` .. but looking at the abe output, I notice every page load - abe was opening the blk00000.dat  file rather than using MySQL [which I have configured abe to use].

My abe.conf looks like this;

```
dbtype MySQLdb
connect-args {"user":"test","db":"abe","passwd":"test"}
upgrade
port 2750
host localhost
```

I have checked the 'abe' MySQL database and the data is in there, I am just unable to figure out why abe isn't querying that and instead opening the blk00000.dat file. . . which is making every request I make to abe unbearably slow.

So my question is:
How to make Abe query MySQL instead of reading from the bitcoin block.dat for each request ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm still loading the blockchain into my database, but are you starting Abe with the --config option pointing to your configuration file?

See line 49 in https://github.com/bitcoin-abe/bitcoin-abe/blob/master/README-MYSQL.txt

Comment: Yes I specify the absolute path to the config file when firing up abe, still nothing working :(

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I am having the same problem.